# can't insert Facebook interstitial ads into react-native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to use [react-native-fbads](https://github.com/callstack-io/react-native-fbads) in my react-native app (I've never used facebookAds) for inserting an Interstitial Ads.

This is what I've done in one of my app component (after `react-native install react-native-fbads`):

```
import { InterstitialAdManager } from 'react-native-fbads';

constructor(props) {
     InterstitialAdManager.showAd("XXXXX_XXXXX")  // this is line 16
    .then(didClick => {console.log("clicked")})
    .catch(error => {console.log("error")})
}
```

but I keep get this error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'CTKInterstitialAdManager.showAd')`

Answer (score 1):

Have you try running `react-native link react-native-fbads`?

This will automatically link the library's native dependencies to your iOS/Android projects.